# Show partial view below the current row in the table by clicking the link

Tags: html, jquery, asp.net-core

class in models

```
public class Item
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    
    [Display(Name = "Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    
    public int? ParentId { get; set; }
}
```

actions in ItemsController

```
public class ItemsController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult ParentsIndex()
    {
        var items = _items.GetParents();
        return View("Parents", items);
    }

    public IActionResult Show(int id)
    {
        var children = _items.GetChildrenByID(id).ToList();
        return PartialView("_Show", children);
    }
}
```

view Parents

```
@model IEnumerable<Item>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "title";
    Layout = "_Layout";
}

<h1 class="text-center">
    <i class="fas fa-comments-dollar text-success"></i>
    Items
</h1>

<table class="table table-borderless table-hover rounded box-shadow shadow">
    <thead class="thead-light">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                <a asp-controller="Items" asp-action="Show" asp-route-id="@item.ID">
                    @Html.DisplayName(item.Name)
                </a>
            </td>
            <td>
                @{ await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_DropDownWithButtons", item.ID); }
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

view Show

```
@model IEnumerable<Item>

@{
    Layout = "_Layout";
}

@{
    var children = new List<Item>();
    if (Model.Count() != 0)
    {
        children = Model.ToList();
    }
}

<table class="table table-borderless table-hover rounded box-shadow shadow">
    <tbody>
    @{
        await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ShowTableChildren", children.ToList());
    }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

partial view _ShowTableChildren

```
@model IEnumerable<Item>

<div>
    <table class="table table-borderless table-hover rounded box-shadow shadow">
        <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr data-id="@item.ID" class="clickableRow">
                <td>
                    <a asp-route-id="@item.ID">
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
                    </a>
                </td>
                <td>
                    @{ await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_DropDownWithButtons", item.ID); }
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

How can I show partial view below the current row in the table by clicking the link.

I am not familiar with jQuery and tried to do it according to the tutorials, but I didn’t succeed.

As I understand it, the algorithm is approximately the following:

I need to assign id to an html element

Create an empty div with id

In the script, create a method that will do this

Comment: You said ```How can I show partial view below the current row in the table by clicking the link.``` and also said you are not familiar in jquery,but i did not found here any jquery code yet. what you actually want?

Comment: I've added my code snippet below, if you feel it helpful to you, could you pls accept it as the answer by pick the √ ？ And if there's any further issue on it, just kindly share your problems here : )

Comment: Is there any progress sir?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you wanna a feature like click the row then show the children items behind that row. If so, you should use [View Components](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-components?view=aspnetcore-5.0#view-components) here. As [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/partial?view=aspnetcore-5.0#when-to-use-partial-views) said：

> Don't use a partial view where complex rendering logic or code
> execution is required to render the markup. Instead of a partial view,
> use a view component.

Here I'll post my code snippet to show my test result:

click the `show details` button will toggle the child model.
[image]

View controller, I use hard code data model here:

```
public class ItemsController : Controller
    {
        public IActionResult ParentsIndex()
        {
            var items = new List<Item>
            {
                new Item{ ID=1,Name="item1" },
                new Item{ ID=2,Name="item2" }
            };
            return View("Parents", items);
        }
    }
```

And this is my parents.cshtml

```
@model IEnumerable<Item>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "title";
    //Layout = "_Layout";
}

<h1 class="text-center">
    <i class="fas fa-comments-dollar text-success"></i>
    Items
</h1>

<table class="table table-borderless table-hover rounded box-shadow shadow">
    <thead class="thead-light">
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <a asp-controller="Items" asp-action="Show" asp-route-id="@item.ID">
                        @Html.DisplayName(item.Name)
                    </a>
                </td>
                <td> <a href="#" onclick="toggleshow(@item.ID)">show details</a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="display:none;" id="row_@item.ID">
                <td colspan="2">
                    @await Component.InvokeAsync("PriorityList", new { id = item.ID })
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>

<script>
    function toggleshow(id) {
        $("#row_" + id).toggle();
    }
</script>
```

Then followed the walkthrough to creating component, my `PriorityListViewComponent.cs`:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using WebApplication1.Models;

namespace WebApplication1.ViewComponents
{
    public class PriorityListViewComponent : ViewComponent
    {
        public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync(int id)
        {
            var children = new List<Item>
            {
                new Item{ ID=11,Name="chile_item1",ParentId=id },
                new Item{ ID=21,Name="chile_item2",ParentId=id }
            };
            return View(children);
        }
    }
}
```

Then here's the `Default.cshtml`, pls note this file should put in the correct folder or it won't be find. I put it under Shared folder. [Details here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-components?view=aspnetcore-5.0#view-search-path):

```
@model IEnumerable<Item>

<table>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr data-id="@item.ID" class="clickableRow">
            <td>
                <a asp-route-id="@item.ID">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
                </a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. You understood my task very well and this is exactly what I need

Comment: Thanks for your reply and I'm glad to see it worked for you : )